# Using delimiters on scanner to read multiples lines from a text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

Using scanner we can read next string, next line etc. But how can we read multiple lines into a string using scanner. Suppose the input something like

```
FIRSTNAME="John"
LASTNAME="Taylor"
ADDRESS="line1
line2
line3
line4"
```

output should look something like

```
John, "Taylor"
```

and how to we read entire address into a single string variable so that when we print it should like

```
"line1
 line2
 line3
 line4"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A good question should show what you have tried, preferably with code, and a clear explanation of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the lines one by one using the [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method of Scanner and keep appending them in a [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) with the `\n` at the end of each line. Once you are done reading all the lines, [`StringBuffer#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#toString%28%29) will give you your desired result.

In your case, you need to read the line and [`String#split(regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) it on the `=` symbol and take the second element of the resultant array.